# Angular 8 - How do I get the closest parent by class name?

Tags: javascript, angular, selector, angular-directive, angular8

This is what I am trying to achieve  (Consider this as an example scenario) -

- Element 1

  - Element 2
  - Element 3

    - Element 4

Element 4 is my angular component. I would like to set its height based on the heights of Element 1 and Element 2.

Element 1 and Element 2 could be anywhere in the element hierarchy i.e. they don't necessarily have to be immediate parent or sibling. I would like to be able to get references of Element 1 and Element 2 by their class names and get their heights.

What is the best way to query for a parent element in angular by class name or any other selector?

Comment: Dynamically controlling the height of elements based upon the height of other dynamic content is very problematic in Angular. It's unlikely that simply referencing the elements will be enough to make this work. You'll run into change detection problems trying to keep element 4 up to date when 1 and 2 are changed.

Comment: Are Element 1/2/3 Angular components as well or only Element 4  is angular component?

Comment: @tgralex Only Element 4 is an angular component. All other elements may or may not be angular components.

Comment: @Reactgular What do you suggest in such case? Would you recommend using jQuery for that purpose?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with querying the DOM elements. That is relatively simple to do, but how will you know if element 1 or 2 have changed? If element 4 depends upon the heights of those elements, and those elements change later then how will element 4 know it needs to change its height also? This is a common problem when doing the layout of DOM objects via JavaScript. I would recommend you rethink your approach before you start trying to solve the layout problem via JavaScript. Try to find a CSS approach first.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you're aware, this isn't really a best practice type of approach. The Iteration happens 100 times hopefully looking for a parent element based on a class name.

```
/**
 * findParentElementByClass, returns an parent element based on a 
 * class name. This parent class name is chained off the required 
 * child component.
 * 
 * @param  {String} parentClass    // parent class
 * @param  {String} componentClass // Element 4 class in your case
 * @return {Node} componentParent          
 */
function findParentElementByClass(parentClass, componentClass) {
    let componentParent = document.querySelector(`.${componentClass}`).parentNode;

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (componentParent.classList.contains(`.${parentClass}`)) {
            break;
        } else {
            componentParent = componentParent.parentNode;
        }
    }

    return componentParent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I will definitely try this out and see if it affects the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to control height by CSS?
like:

**div p** Selects all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` elements

**div > p** Selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a `<div>` element

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

I'd recommend using classes though, like

```
element1-class > element4-class {
   height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: The entire hierarchy is inside a draggable and resizable grid layout. That is why I would require a dynamic solution.